# How to count how many word in string?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, c-strings, strstr

I want to know how to count how many words are in a string.
I use `strstr` to compare and it works but only works for one time

like this

```
char buff = "This is a real-life, or this is just fantasy";
char op = "is";

if (strstr(buff,op)){
    count++;
}
printf("%d",count);
```

and the output is 1 but there are two "is" in the sentence, please tell me.

Comment: The initialization of your *single* character variables should make your compiler scream at you. As should the call to `strstr` which expects strings and not characters.

Comment: As for your problem, what does [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) *return*? And do you know how to use loops?

Comment: "but only works for one time" It's not in a loop so what did you expect...

Comment: First of all you should use for or while loop to count the occurences. Secondly you must know proper use and return type for a function. strstr() is used when you want to find whether a substring exists in a given string or not, so this is inappropriate. Search on the internet as you will find a solution there.

Comment: "aaaaa" checked against "aa" should return what number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you have to write the declarations at least like

```
char buff[] = "This is a real-life, or this is just fantasy";
const char *op = "is";
```

Also if you need to count words you have to check whether words are separated by white spaces.

You can do the task the following way

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//...

size_t n = strlen( op );
for ( const char *p = buff; ( p = strstr( p, op ) ) != NULL; p += n )
{
    if ( p == buff || isblank( ( unsigned char )p[-1] ) )
    {
        if ( p[n] == '\0' || isblank( ( unsigned char )p[n] ) )
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
printf("%d",count);
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char buff[] = "This is a real-life, or this is just fantasy";
    const char *op = "is";
    size_t n = strlen( op );

    size_t count = 0;

    for ( const char *p = buff; ( p = strstr( p, op ) ) != NULL; p += n )
    {
        if ( p == buff || isblank( ( unsigned char )p[-1] ) )
        {
            if ( p[n] == '\0' || isblank( ( unsigned char )p[n] ) )
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf( "The word \"%s\" is encountered %zu time(s).\n", op, count );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The word "is" is encountered 2 time(s).
```

Comment: With OP's example, does this result in 2 or more as `is` is in `This`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It is unclear from the question whether he needs to count a substring or a word separated by white spaces,

Comment: "count a substring or a word separated by white spaces," --> OP does have "but there are _two_ "is" in the sentence" so it looks like only whole words count. I'd expect `"is this is this is"` count as 3, not 5.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string, in a *loop*.

As OP has "but there are two "is" in the sentence", it is not enough just to look for `"is"` as that occurs 4x, twice in `"This"`.  Code needs to parse the string for the idea of a "word".

Case sensitively is also a concern.

```
char buff = "This is a real-life, or this is just fantasy";
char op = "is";

char *p = buff;
char *candidate;
while ((candidate = strstr(p, op)) {
  // Add code to test if candidate is a stand-alone word
  // Test if candidate is beginning of buff or prior character is a white-space.
  // Test if candidate is end of buff or next character is a white-space/punctuation.
  p += strlen(op); // advance
}
```

For me, I would not use `strstr()`, but look for "words" with `isalpha()`.

```
// Concept code
size_t n = strlen(op);
while (*p) {
  if (isalpha(*p)) {  // Start of word
    // some limited case insensitive compare
    if (strnicmp(p, op, n) == 0 && !isalpha(p[n]) {  
      count++;
    }
    while (isalpha(*p)) p++;  // Find end of word
  } else {
    p++;
  }
}
```